# Munin CPU usage graph doesn't go all the way to 100% on a busy VM

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, munin

We've noticed that our Munin CPU graphs look a little odd on VMs that are quite busy.

VM is running Ubuntu 8.04, VMware tools up-to-date and running, host is VMware ESXi 4.1.0 build 348481.

This is from a physical server:

[image: Munin CPU graph on physical server]

This is from a VM:

[image: Munin CPU graph on virtual server]

Notice that the VM has white areas at the top of the graph and the individual numbers don't add up to 200. This hasn't always been like this and I am struggling to think what could cause this.

Can anyone shed some light on this weirdness?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware of what Munin actually monitors.

If Munin reads the CPU frequency, and takes the current usage as a percentage of that physical maximum, the readings will be off when the hypervisor did not assign the full CPU core to the guest.

That was just an example - the Munin documentation (and plugin source) will tell you exactly what is measured.